# Is there python command that converts py to exe?

Tags: python

I know that you can simply write `"python -m auto_py_to_exe"` in cmd or `os.system("python -m auto_py_to_exe")` in python to convert python file in exe file but what i ask is is there a command that you write like `os.convert("file_name",".exe")` and that it converts it to `.exe` without you doing anything?

Comment: No, you misunderstand how this works.  It's not an OS operation.  Python has to be involved.  `auto_py_to_exe` is one good way, but all the alternatives work the same way.  It's very much like compiling a C++ program.  You have to invoke a compiler.

Comment: @Tim Robert I used that just as a example so that people know what do I mean.

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing.  Even if there were an `os.convert` option, that's still not "without you doing anything".  How is that different from the command that DOES work?  You've just spelled in differently.

Comment: @Tim Roberts I was thinking without you choosing any options like path.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it coulds be do natively. There are some converters like "pyinstaller" you could install with pip.
After you can start a conversion with one line:

```
pyinstaller options… ~/myproject/source/myscript.py
```

[more info about pyinstaller](https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/usage.html)